# A custom class of process or thread cannot be pickled

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, pickle

As you can see here, I can pickle both classes `A` and `B`:

```
import pickle

class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

>>> pickle.dumps(A())  # Wroks
>>> pickle.dumps(B())  # Wroks
```

Also, I can pickle both classes `multiprocessing.Process` and `threading.Thread`:

```
import multiprocessing
import pickle
import threading

>>> pickle.dumps(multiprocessing.Process())  # Wroks
>>> pickle.dumps(threading.Thread())  # Wroks
```

But, I can't pickle a custom class that inherits from `multiprocessing.Process` or `threading.Thread`:

```
import multiprocessing
import pickle
import threading

class CustomProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    pass

class CustomThread(threading.Thread):
    pass

>>> pickle.dumps(CustomProcess())  # TypeError: Pickling an AuthenticationString object is disallowed for security reasons
>>> pickle.dumps(CustomThread())  # TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object
```

Is there a way to solve it?

BTW, I'm using Python 3.11, Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can implement the `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` methods to override how the custom objects are pickled.

Comment: As a hack for processes, you can overwrite `CustomProcess()._config['authkey'] = b"whatever"` so it is no longer an instance of `AuthenticationString` which is what implements the pickling guard. Note this was implemented for security reasons, so consider what this will mean for you. On a broader note, Threads and Processes are not meant to be traded around or persisted to disk because lots of other things will begin to break. When subclassing either of these, it is best to stick to overriding the `run` method and calling the original `start` method to lauch the task.